# Field 'id' expected a number but got 'ANPKUR0724' while Importing Data in Django

Tags: django, django-models, error-handling, django-admin, django-import-export

I have two models, related through a Foreign Key, when im uploading the Model having Foreign key , the id value which is auto created is taking value of the Field which is the foreign key. What could be the possible reason?.

```
 class Station(models.Model):
          BS_ID = models.TextField(max_length=20,unique=True)
          BS_Name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
          City = models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True)
          State = models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True)
          City_Tier = models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True)
          Lat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=5,null=True,blank=True)
          Long = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=5,null=True,blank=True)
    
    class CustomerLVPN(models.Model):
      Customer_Name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
      Order_Type = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
      Feasibility_ID = models.IntegerField(null=True)
      Circuit_ID = models.CharField(max_length=250,null=True,blank=True)
      Req_BW = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6,decimal_places=3,null=True,blank=True)
      City = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
      State = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
      Region =models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
      L2_Lat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6,decimal_places=3,null=True,blank=True)
      L2_Long = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6,decimal_places=3,null=True,blank=True)
      BS_ID = models.ForeignKey(Station,to_field='BS_ID',related_name='ConfirmedCustomer',on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
```

So when im Uploading data for CustomerLVPN model im getting the following error -
"BS_ID
Field 'id' expected a number but got 'ANPKUR0724'."
[image]

Below is the Resource Code:

```
class StationResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model=Station
        exclude = ['id']
        use_bulk=True
        batch_size = 500

class StationAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class=StationResource


class LVPNResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomerLVPN
        use_bulk = True
        batch_size = 500

class LVPNAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = LVPNResource
```

Comment: can you post your Resource declaration and an example import row (redacted)

Comment: Added the Resource Declaration above.

Comment: And for the import im using an excel file having values against each of the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your `LVPNResource` you need to associated a [`ForeignKeyWidget`](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_widgets.html#import_export.widgets.ForeignKeyWidget) with your `bs_id` field:

```py
bs_id = fields.Field(
        column_name='BS_ID',
        attribute='BS_ID',
        widget=ForeignKeyWidget(Station, 'BS_ID'))
```